# This patent seems to be prior art to a patent listed in this Indegogo project?

Tags: international

In reference to the patent: [US7798499](https://www.google.com/patents/US7798499)

[Jurni ultimate sit on carry on suitcase](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/jurni-the-ultimate-sit-on-carry-on-suitcase#/)

Which invention infringes the other?  In other words is the Jurni developed in CA 2000 unreferenced prior art to US7798499 or the other way around?

Comment: What about it are you asking about? This is a community-run website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patents or Applications. We do not have a direct channel to the patent holder so they will not get your message here.

Comment: I could not find the patent that Jurni references but it's main claim is an I-Beam support.

Comment: Hey Robert, welcome to Ask Patents. A community member here just edited your post, and changed it in a way that may or may not fulfill your original question. I approved the suggested edit, because I think this new version will likely address your question as best as our community will be able to. If you'd like, please feel free to follow-up with an [edit] of your own, but please remember that we do not have a way of communicating with the patent owner directly.